# Choosing between Dependency Inversion and Dependency "Delegation" to a third module

Tags: architecture, solid, layers, dependency-management, dependency-inversion

Suppose I have `MasterPackage` containing a `Master` class, and `BlasterPackage` containing `Blaster` class. Since `Master` needs a `Blaster` to work, the higher level `MasterPackage` *depends* directly on lower-level `BlasterPackage`.

Using classic Dependency Inversion, one would add `IBlaster` (or `AbstractBlaster`) to `MasterPackage`, thus *inverting* dependency between the packages.

But while facing this problem, I realized I could create a *third* package - let's name it `MasterBlasterInterfaces` - and put `IBlaster` there. That would "delegate" the dependency to that third, common package, and the original two packages would be now decoupled from one another.

But then, if I have a higer-level package called `ThunderDome`, it will have to deal directly with `BlasterPackage`, wouldn't it? I feel like it sort of violates encapsulation, while with direct dependency `Master` could possibly abstract away the very existence of `Blaster`.

So the question is:

> Is there a good set of criteria to choose between inversion vs. delegation of dependencies? And how one vs. other impacts use of the packages by higher-level application layers?

Answer (score 3):

Inverting the dependency as you have described it is only OK if you control the other package, and if this direct dependency is acceptable. For a lot of software, that is entirely OK. But most obviously, this doesn't work if your `BlasterPackage` is an external library you rely on.

The magic of introducing an `IBlaster` interface is that `MasterPackage` and `BlasterPackage` can work together without having a direct dependency relationship, and without being written by the same person/team/organization. Usually, this is not done by putting `IBlaster` into a separate package that both modules depend on. Instead, `IBlaster` would be part of `MasterPackage`, and you would introduce an *adapter* module. The dependencies can be illustrated like this:

[image: an UML diagram illustrating that MasterPackage and BlasterPackage do not have to be directly connected]

The adapter depends on both packages, but the `Master` only depends on `IBlaster`. Such adapters get extremely useful when writing unit tests, and wanting to mock out the `BlasterPackage`. Of course, the `MasterPackage` will require some conforming adapter to be provided, but there is no concrete dependency on the `BlasterAdapter`. Even when you make all dependencies explicit and configurable, at some point the interface consumers and interface providers will have to be connected (dependency *injection*).

Comment: Nice! So do you thing it is correct to say that `ThunderDome` module, using a `Master` class, could also inject the `Blaster` dependency into it? And what would be a sensible way for the `ThunderDome` module to get/create an instance of `Blaster` in the first place? Mind that am not currently using any dependency injection / IoC framework, and don't plan to do so unless unavoidable.